# How to get UIView Controller of custom cell contained in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, custom-cell

I have a view controller 
in that having a table view in that a Custom cell.

I have a button in a custom cell

```
MyViewController
---View
------TableView
-------------Custom cell
-------------------UIButton
```

I want to **implement the button action for that button in the custom cell, in the Custom cell class.**

I want to present another viewcontoler called mailPage by clicking on button for thet

```
-(IBAction)webButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
  [self presentModalViewController:mailpage animated:YES];
}
```

But here **self means CustomCell,** even i **tried with superview** i didn't get my view contoller to represent in place of self

I tried like this but no use.

```
MyViewController *myViewController =self.superview
```

How to get my View controler containing the current custom cell

Comment: how you are using custom cell in table view? Post that code....

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend you  place your view controller presentation logic in a view controller, rather than a `UITableViewCell`.

As you're already using a custom cell, this will be fairly straightforward. Simply define a new protocol for your custom cell, and have your view controller act as a delegate. Or alternatively, as per [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910323/delegate-from-button-tap-inside-custom-uitableviewcell) you can forgo the delegate entirely, and simply have your view controller act as the target for your button.

Your custom `UITableViewCell` really shouldn't have any dependencies or knowledge of the view controller it's being displayed in.

Answer (score 2):

well the easy way is to set an unique tag for the button in the cell and in cellForRowAtIndexpath method you can get the button instance as

```
UIButton *sampleButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
```

and set the action as

```
    [sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sampleButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and set up the action in the viewcontroller

```
-(void)sampleButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OpenHouseListCustomCell";
    OpenHouseListCustomCell *cell = (OpenHouseListCustomCell *)[tblOpenHouses dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        NSArray* nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OpenHouseListCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    cell.btn1.tag = indexpath.row;
    return cell;
}

-(void) ButtonClicked {
    //your code here...
}
```